# Conan gives error in getting the dependencies

Tags: conan

To get and build the dependencies with conan I gave this command:

```
conan install .. --build=missing --settings compiler.libcxx="libstdc++11"
```

It resulted in this error:

```
ERROR: The default build profile '/home/sohail/.conan2/profiles/default' doesn't exist.

You need to create a default profile (type 'conan profile detect' command)
```

or specify your own profile with:

```
'--profile:build=<myprofile>'
```

I found two `conan` directories in my home directory, one is `.conan` and the other is `.conan2`.

In .`conan` there is a profile directory whereas in .`conan2`, there is no profile directory.

I added this

```
"export CONAN_USER_HOME=$HOME/.conan" in ~/.bashrc. and echo 
 $CONAN_USER_HOME returned /home/sohail/.conan
```

But when I entered the above `conan` install command it gives the same error as above.

I copied the profiles directory from `.conan` and pasted it in `.conan2` directory and run the above command but it gave this error:

```
ERROR: Error reading '/home/sohail/.conan2/profiles/default' profile: 
ConfigParser: Unrecognized field 'build_requires'
```

I used terminal in `CLion 2021.2.4`.
What should I do now to bring my settings to `.conan directory`.

I explained it above.

Comment: You are mixing Conan 1.X and Conan 2.0 concepts. If you are running Conan2, your home directory is ``.conan2`` and it will not contain a default profile automatically, the error message above is telling it "type ``conan profile detect`` command"

Comment: In Conan 2 the profile defines ``[tool_requires]``, not ``[build_requires]``

Comment: @drodri You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems concepts, commands and caches from Conan 1.X and 2.0 are being mixed:

- Conan 1.X and Conan 2.0 uses different, incompatible caches. Conan 1.X uses `.conan` by default and Conan 2.0 uses `.conan2` by default
- It is not valid to copy files from one cache to the other in the general case, and it can break in different ways. Some configuration files are not compatible.

In Conan 2.0 the `default` profile is not automatically created, so the `profiles` folder will be empty by default. Conan 2.0 command will fail to work if a profile is not specified and the default one doesn't exist. It is possible to create a default one with `conan profile detect` 2.0 command.

Also, in Conan 2.0, the profiles mandate `[tool_requires]`, and build_requires is not longer possible, this is why you are seeing that error.